# Xtext (DSL file) to Ecore

Tags: dsl, xtext, eclipse-emf-ecore, emf

I have an Xtext project and a couple of sample DSL files. I can open these files with "Sample Ecore Model Editor" and validate that it conforms to the metamodel generated by Xtext. However, I cannot create an "EMF Project" or an "EMF Generator Model" due to the fact that the DSL file is not recognized as Ecore.

My question is, how can I export an ecore from my `example.dsl` file?

P.S. I believe this is possible due to this [fact](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Xtext/FAQ#How_can_I_load_my_model_in_the_EMF_reflective_model_editor.C2.A0.3F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways to get your hands on ecore meta-model for your DSL

- In standard wizard-generated Xtext-Project the ecore meta-model get derived from your grammar. The workflow generator saves generated meta-model into

  ```
  [Project]/src-gen/[your-package]/[grammar-name].ecore
  ```

  For example:

  ```
  org.xtext.example.mydsl/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/MyDsl.ecore
  ```
- You can also write ecore meta-model yourself and use if with your grammar. This is not a simple process, but it provides more flexibility. For more information see: http://blog.efftinge.de/2009/11/xtext-using-existing-ecore-models.html

Comment: Thanks you for the fast reply. I know that *.ecore is generated in the path you specified. My problem is that I am willing to transform my model instance. Please see the helpful image below:
http://imgur.com/mX4QjQW

Comment: Do you want to convert dsl to xmi?

Comment: Check this forum message: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/292631/801725/#msg_801725 Check the entire forum thread for more information

Comment: Thanks again. I will try the proposed solution.